# Unexpected attribute in generated XML

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm generating this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <sitemap xmlns="" id="0">
      <loc>http://x.ae/sitemap-url/ae/sitemap-index.xml</loc>
      <lastmod>2015-02-19</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
   <sitemap xmlns="" id="1">
      <loc>http://x.bh/sitemap-url/bh/sitemap-index.xml</loc>
      <lastmod>2015-02-19</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
   <sitemap xmlns="" id="2">
      <loc>http://x.eg/sitemap-url/eg/sitemap-index.xml</loc>
      <lastmod>2015-02-19</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
   <sitemap xmlns="" id="3">
      <loc>http://x.ma/sitemap-url/ma/sitemap-index.xml</loc>
      <lastmod>2015-02-19</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
   <sitemap xmlns="" id="4">
      <loc>http://x.om/sitemap-url/om/sitemap-index.xml</loc>
      <lastmod>2015-02-19</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
   <sitemap xmlns="" id="5">
      <loc>http://x.qa/sitemap-url/qa/sitemap-index.xml</loc>
      <lastmod>2015-02-19</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
   <sitemap xmlns="" id="6">
      <loc>http://x.tn/sitemap-url/tn/sitemap-index.xml</loc>
      <lastmod>2015-02-19</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

I try to delete this attribute: `<sitemap xmlns="">` but it's no possible. 
What I'm doing wrong?

This is my code to generate XML:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        //ROOT ELEMENT:
        Element rootElement = doc.createElementNS("http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9", "sitemapindex");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);



        SortedSet<Country> countries = locationDao.readAllCountriesSorted();
        int i =0;
        for(Country c : countries){
            Element siteMap = doc.createElement("sitemap");

            siteMap.setAttribute("id", String.valueOf(i));
            //PUT AN ID 
            Element loc = doc.createElement("loc");
            Element lastMod = doc.createElement("lastmod");

            loc.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("http://"+c.getDomain()+"/sitemap-url/"+c.getCode().toLowerCase()+"/sitemap-index.xml"));
            lastMod.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(DateUtils.getCurrentDateString()));

            rootElement.appendChild(siteMap);
            siteMap.appendChild(loc);
            siteMap.appendChild(lastMod);
         i++;   
        }

        ;//always appear.   
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();


        //IDENTEM EL RESULTAT
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        //transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        //Si ho volem mostrar en un file:
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("sitemapTest.xml"));
        //StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        System.out.println("Document ready....");
```

I try to delete with `removeAttribute` method or `removeAttNs` but seems not working..

Comment: you mean xmlns="" attribute?

Comment: yes  xmnls in sitemap node...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your `sitemap`, `loc`, `lastmod` elements in the proper namespace ( you currently create it in the null namespace, which in this case is not the default namespace) :

```
 Element siteMap = doc.createElementNS("http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9", "sitemap");
 //...
 Element loc = doc.createElementNS("http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9", "loc");
 Element lastMod = doc.createElementNS("http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9", "lastmod");
```

Comment: but here http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#escaping doesn't specify anything..Will be correct?

Comment: Yes, it will. You must distinguish between the abstract concept of a namespace and the lexicalisation in an xml file: the abstract concept says, that all your elements in the sitemap tree belong to the same namespace that you set for the `sitemapindex` element. In the xml output, it is only written on the root of the respective subtree (which in this case is the root element of the whole xml file). as you set it as the default namespace,no prefixes are attached to the descendant elements' name.

Answer (score 0):

It is a while since i did XML with DOM in Java but if i remember correctly you must set the namespace on all elements, so your dom knows which namespace to use. If it does not know this, it will create an empty XML-Namepsace (short: xmlns) which results in the empty attribute you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an attribute, it's a namespace declaration. The effect of the namespace declaration is to ensure that your sitemap elements are not in a namespace. It's needed because when you created the sitemap elements, you asked for them to be in no namespace. If you want them in the namespace "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9", you must create them in that namespace, which you do using createElementNS().